# Selecting different columns from 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

Before asking, i just want to tell you that i am looking solution for my problem since 1 week, i tried many times to solve my problem myself but failed.

I have 3 different tables tables

1. users
2. wallet_transactions
3. wallet_payment

I want to get combine results from these tables.I tried **join** method of sql and get some result but no required.

**Here is my USER table**

```
     userId  User_name           Wallet
       1    Abdulrehmanahmad      1107.5
       2    Azzhar789             1089
       3    azharmehmood          1022
       4    komalali              1252
       5    Muhammadbasheer        800
```

**2: **Table is wallet_transactions****  (Data of Withdrwal request sent)

```
    Transaction_id    user_id   Node_type           amount    type(in/out)     date
          1             3      withdrawal_wallet      1022       out          2022-07-22 
          2             2      withdrawal_wallet      1089       out          2022-07-22              
          3             4      withdrawal_wallet      400        out          2022-07-22
          4             4      withdrawal_wallet      452       out           2022-07-22
          5             4      withdrawal_wallet      400       out           2022-07-21
```

**3: Table is wallet_payment**

(status 1 is for withdrawal accepted , -1 is for rejected , 0 for pending)

```
         user_id     amount        time        status
            3         1022      2022-07-23        1
            2         1089      2022-07-23        0
            4          400      2022-07-23        -1
            4          452      2022-07-23        1
            4          400      2022-07-22        1
```

I want to get result from these tables like this.

```
            sr  user_name   Latest_Withdrawal       Time
             1  Komalali        400           3 hours ago
             2  komalali        452           8 hours ago
             3  Sadiakhan       250           1 day ago
             4  Fidakhan211     380           1 day ago
             5  alifk1218       481           1 day ago
```

Here is a code that i use for get this result

```
  SELECT users.user_name , wallet_transactions.amount ,wallet_transactions.date, 
  wallet_payments.time from users 
  INNER JOIN wallet_transactions  ON  users.user_id=wallet_transactions.user_id
  INNER JOIN wallet_payments ON wallet_payments.user_id=wallet_transactions.user_id
  where wallet_transactions.node_type ='withdraw_wallet' && 
  wallet_transactions.type='out' && wallet_payments.status=1
  GROUP BY wallet_payments.time 
  ORDER BY wallet_payments.time desc ;
```

And this query gives me like this result.

```
  ID    XD USERS    Latest Withdrawal   Time
   1    komalali         400          2022-08-16 17:16:00
   2    komalali         400          2022-08-16 17:09:38
   3    Sadiakhan        250          2022-08-15 17:23:36
   4    Fidakhan211      380          2022-08-15 10:23:06
   5    alifk1218        481          2022-08-15 07:30:01
```

Comment: Okay, there's a lot going on here. First of all, the column names you mention in your tables don't match up with the ones on your query. Please make sure that they do in the future, that saves us all quite some time. Then, the desired result doesn't match any possibility of combinations of the data in your examples. This makes it all the more confusing. Next the query you provide cannot work because there's a `GROUP BY` and you use nonaggregated columns in your selection. Could you please correct your data and your query.

Comment: You could also post a DB Fiddle with your work, I started one already which you can use if you want: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/r3dePBHH3Ji4SmptiDCpx4/1

Comment: Sir i uploaded my actual database data in DB Fiddle  [link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/r3dePBHH3Ji4SmptiDCpx4/6)